# How to change multiple columns into rows in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013

My data is in three columns.
I want each column to appear on the new line, without overwriting the existing line.
Kindly help... Thanks

```
![How do I attain the Desired output? ][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEGeG.png
```

My Excel Sheet

```
Original Lines      
<sentence>  AAA </sentence>
<sentence>  BBB </sentence>
<sentence>  CCC </sentence>

After Col Transpose     
<sentence>  <sentence>  <sentence>
AAA         BBB         CCC
</sentence> </sentence> </sentence>

Desired Output
    <sentence>
    AAA
    </sentence>
    <sentence>
    BBB
    </sentence>
    <sentence>
    CCC
    </sentence>
```

---

I have tried transpose but all appear in the same row.
I want it to appear on separate row.
Kindly Help
Thanks.

```
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO3s3.png

Original Lines      
<sentence>  AAA </sentence>
<sentence>  BBB </sentence>
<sentence>  CCC </sentence>

After Col Transpose     
<sentence>  <sentence>  <sentence>
AAA BBB CCC
</sentence> </sentence> </sentence>

Desired Output
<sentence>
AAA
</sentence>
<sentence>
BBB
</sentence>
<sentence>
CCC
</sentence>
```

Comment: Copy each column and PasteSpecialTranspose onto a fresh row.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a formula? Put this in D1 and drag down:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/3),INT((((ROW(A1)-1)/3)- (INT((ROW(A1)-1)/3)))*3))
```

It works out an offset matrix using this for the row:

```
=INT((ROW(A1)-1)/3)
```

And this for the column:

```
=INT((((ROW(A1)-1)/3)- (INT((ROW(A1)-1)/3)))*3)
```

Then applies an offset from A1 using that matrix.

Comment: Hi, Having tried it worked cool for me. but my data is of several lines hence the output generated is not printing all the lines. :-(

Comment: It worked finally, thank U very much... Only re-correction =OFFSET($A$1,ROUND(((((ROW(A1)-1)/3),INT((((ROW(A1)-1)/3)- (INT((ROW(A1)-1)/3)))*3),0))